# Is there a "Clone Stencil" for Sculpting a Surface from a Target Area Onto a Destination Area?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, sculpt

[image: mesh]

As you can see in the screenshot there is a rough surface on the left side. My goal is to apply a similar surface to the right side, where the mesh is smooth.

How can this be achieved? Is it possible to create a brush from a given area and use it to apply the same "texture" to another area?